# Apache Zeppelin 0.7.0 on Windows 10 - Issue with interpreters

Tags: linux, windows, apache, apache-zeppelin

1. I downloaded the binary package with all interpreters.
2. I then unzipped the filed and opened a command prompt, cd'd into the folder and typed `bin\zeppelin.cmd` because I'm using Windows 10.
3. The zeppelin server starts and I navigate to `http:localhost:8080/` and can see the introductions and tutorials.
4. I go to create a new note and see that spark is listed as an interpreter binding for the note - great!
5. I type in sc.version and click run and I get 'error' with no output.
6. I get errors on the tutorials as well....nothing works.

The looked in the logs folder and there is no file found. The error no longer shows on the screen so I don't know what my error is. The Jobs section has a red dot for the job but no additional details. I'm not getting anything useful in the command line output.

What am I missing? I have generally always had issues with the interpreters, either on linux or windows. I've tried Windows 7 SP1 and Linux Ubuntu 14, as well as EMR with a reverse proxy and had interpreter connection issues in every case. Do I need to set my JAVA_HOME or any other environment variable in Windows 10? Is there an instruction missing in the quick start? How are you guys getting this up and running in any OS! Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you share logs in the `logs/` directory?

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in the logs folder. Do I need to install spark, hadoop, or scala prior to zeppelin? If so, do I need to reference SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, and JAVA_HOME? It might just be easier for me and others to walk step by step, assume I'm a complete idiot with no prior assumptions, and get this up and running on Linux or Windows 10. Everything online either has issues or is outdated. This tool looks fantastic but a complete headache to troubleshoot. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: It's weird. There should be log in `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/logs` if you started zeppelin at least once. Did you run zeppelin on Ubuntu 14 using the `bin/zeppelin-daemon start` command?

In my case, I am using OSX. I have set `JAVA_HOME` for zeppelin.

Comment: I am not familiar with windows. But at least ubuntu, Zeppelin should work cause zeppelin is tested on ubuntu in travis CI.

Comment: If you want just run tutorial, you can use dockerized zeppelin. I didn't make 0.7.0 image yet, but tell me if you need. (https://github.com/1ambda/docker-zeppelin)

Comment: try redirecting console output to a log file - it might reveal some useful diagnostic messages: c:\InterSystems\zeppelin>bin\zeppelin.cmd > log.txt

Answer (score 0):

It looks as the Spark-Interpreter on the latest version(s) of Zeppelin is broken on Windows!! I've manage to make it work with the following steps (I haven't performed much testing so I'm not sure about it's stability):

- Perform the following copy (and delete not sure why)

`$> cp %SPARK_HOME%\jars\*.jar %ZEPPELIN_HOME%\interpreter\spark`

`$> del %ZEPPELIN_HOME%\interpreter\spark\datanucleus*.jar`

- Modify the following spark interpreter parameter in zeppelin (don't forget to save):

[image]

- In a terminal window run the following (in zeppelin directory)
  set the following environment variable and run the interpreter:

`$> set PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip`

`$> %ZEPPELIN_HOME%\bin\interpreter.cmd -d %ZEPPELIN_HOME%\interpreter\spark\ -p 52677 -l %ZEPPELIN_HOME%\local-repo\2C9VKCB5N`